# JS continue after multiple .load()-functions done

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, load, jquery-deferred

I'm having a problem with an asynchronous JS function. Well I have a function which inserts elements one by one. This works. But I would like to continue after all `.load()`-functions are done.

The way I've implemented the `Deferred()` part is obviously wrong but I have no clue how to achieve this.

Note: I have simplified the code for a better clarity.

```
var d = new jQuery.Deferred();
var i = index;
function loadView() {
    if(i > -1 && i < array.length) {
        if(!jQuery.contains(document.documentElement, $(selector)[0])) {
            /* do stuff here */
            panel.load(myPHPfile, function() {
                $dom.append($(selector));
                i++;
                if(i < array.length) {
                    loadView();
                    d.resolve();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
loadView();

jQuery.when(d).then(function() {
    /* when all elements are insert, do something */
});
```

I am thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `i < array.length` after incrementing, that means you're not done, so you don't want to resolve your Deferred there. Instead:

```
if(i < array.length) {
    loadView();
} else {                   // ***
    d.resolve();
}
```

Separately, you don't need to use `jQuery.when`. Just:

```
d.then(function() {
    /* when all elements are insert, do something */
});
```